# “TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function” when trying to add my custom css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I seriously cannot tell why I'm having this problem. Each time I try to add my custom css file to the header.
I'm using script called onepage-scroll.js
requires to put the file in the header `<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js"></script>` then write the code...
this is my header

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenbex.com/css/onepage-scroll.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenbex.com/css/style.css"> //old css from another page
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <script src="http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js"></script>
    <title>ElectroFen - Team</title>
</head>
```

This way all works fine and does the work,
but once I change it to my local new custom css 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` page goes blank and says

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onepage_scroll is not a function(…)
>   I have no idea what causes the problem ...

my css file starts with this

```
    /* Prefix */



    #mainpage {
        height: 100vh;
        width: 100vw;
    }
    html {
        display: none;
    }

    .col-md-8, .col-md-4 {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
    .row {
       margin-right: 0;
       margin-left: 0;
    }
    /*  HOME PAGE  */
....
```

> EDIT

this is the full code, this way it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenbex.com/css/onepage-scroll.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenbex.com/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <script src="http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js"></script>
    <title>ElectroFen - Team</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <section id="header">
            <!-- code -->
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
                <!-- code -->
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
                <!-- code -->
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
                <!-- code -->
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

After adding my new custom css file `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">` it doesn't work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenbex.com/css/onepage-scroll.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://greenbex.com/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/font-awesome.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"> //this line
    <script src="http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js"></script>
    <title>ElectroFen - Team</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <section id="header">
            <!-- code -->
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
                <!-- code -->
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
                <!-- code -->
        </section>
        <section id="projects">
                <!-- code -->
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and says

> script.js:19 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onepage_scroll is not a function(…)

script.js has

```
//custom script here
    onePageScroll(".main", {
       sectionContainer: "section",     // sectionContainer accepts any kind of selector in case you don't want to use section
       easing: "ease",                  // Easing options accepts the CSS3 easing animation such "ease", "linear", "ease-in", 
                                        // "ease-out", "ease-in-out", or even cubic bezier value such as "cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.420, 1.310)"
       animationTime: 1000,             // AnimationTime let you define how long each section takes to animate
       pagination: true,                // You can either show or hide the pagination. Toggle true for show, false for hide.
       updateURL: false,                // Toggle this true if you want the URL to be updated automatically when the user scroll to each page.
       beforeMove: function(index) {},  // This option accepts a callback function. The function will be called before the page moves.
       afterMove: function(index) {},   // This option accepts a callback function. The function will be called after the page moves.
       loop: true,                     // You can have the page loop back to the top/bottom when the user navigates at up/down on the first/last page.
       keyboard: true,                  // You can activate the keyboard controls
       responsiveFallback: false        // You can fallback to normal page scroll by defining the width of the browser in which
                                        // you want the responsive fallback to be triggered. For example, set this to 600 and whenever 
                                        // the browser's width is less than 600, the fallback will kick in.
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".main").onepage_scroll();
    });
```

Comment: What is `onepage_scroll`? Clearly it's not a function.

Comment: The error means that something is wrong in the script; it has nothing to do with CSS.

Comment: @Pointy But how it works totally fine before adding that specific style sheet ?

Comment: @Gavin here's the link [onepagescoll](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll)

Comment: Do you added Jquery Library file?

Comment: @Ezhil-UIDeveloper everything is added as it has to. jquery is declared at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @user3378165 No I dont replace the css with js ...

Comment: It looks like your onepagescroll.js is not being included correctly. Any 404s in your console?

Comment: Nowhere in that .js file or in what you posted in the question is the name "onepage_scroll" mentioned. There **must** be other JavaScript involved that you *haven't* posted. Without seeing it, nobody can help much, though I will point out that the "onepagescroll.js" file you're importing has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Can you post the entire code that causes the error?

Comment: @Pointy Actually, if you visit the link the OP posted, it looks like the onepagescroll library has jQuery as a dependency.

Comment: `To add this to your website, simply include the latest jQuery library together with jquery.onepage-scroll.js, onepage-scroll.css into your document's <head> ...`

Comment: @Gavin ??? where exactly do you see any reference to jQuery in that code? (Look at the code in the link posted in the question itself, not at some related github you've searched for.)

Comment: Do you have the style.css on your css folder?

Comment: @Pointy I haven't searched for it, the OP gave the link for the onepagescroll library he is clearly using and having issues with. My last comment is directly from the documentation for it. Please remove your comments.

Comment: @Gavin no, I will not remove my comments because they are directly applicable to the question **as posted**.  The code in the question links to http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js which, as you could plainly see if you'd simply look at it via your browser, is the "pure JS" version that does not require jQuery.

Comment: @user3378165 I did add more code

Comment: @Bououm the last 3 lines of "script.js" are unnecessary and should be removed. That's your problem.

Comment: @Pointy It didn't really work... Guess the only solution I have is to re code the whole page.

Comment: It seems that you are confusing two versions of that plugin. There's a "pure JS" version (which you are currently using in the code you posted), and there's *also* a jQuery version. Your script.js code is trying to initialize the tool with *both* initialization methods, and that's wrong.

Comment: @pointy > **To add this to your website, simply include the latest jQuery library together with jquery.onepage-scroll.js, onepage-scroll.css into your document's <head> and call the function as follows:**//
**Container "Main" must be one level below the body tag in order to make it work full page. Now call the function to activate as follows:** 
Im just following what he said on his documentation which worked for me perfectly in two websites before.

Comment: If you were to include "jquery.onepage-scroll.js", you would be right. **You did not include that script.** You included the "pure JS" version instead.

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using the pure version of the plugin, remove the line `$(".main").onepage_scroll();`

The plugin has already been loaded, and the re-initialization is not needed, which is also causing problems.

## Edit:

You've been using this [plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/purejs-onepage-scroll), `https://github.com/peachananr/purejs-onepage-scroll`, jQuery not required.

But you've used the initialization of this [plugin](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll), `https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll`, jQuery required.

Comment: Well I was using the second one... that requires jquery.

Comment: Open http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js, you'll see that its the pure version.

Comment: correct me if im wrong, but in the [documentation](https://github.com/peachananr/onepage-scroll) have said add greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js with a jquery library in the header. and then call the function to activate `(".main").onepage_scroll({ ...` same as I have in my script.js

Comment: @Bououm click that link in the comment above, which is the URL you posted in your question. Look at the code in there and see if you can find any reference to jQuery. You will not. That code is the "pure JS" version.

Answer (score 0):

May be need plug in jquery?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js"></script>

<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/script.js"></script>
```

The boot order is important

Comment: No, as you can see if you look at it yourself that "onepagescroll.js" file has no jQuery dependencies.

Comment: I have the jquery plugin otherwise it won't work when I don't add that css file

Comment: @Bououm there's no way that the presence/absence of a CSS file link is going to cause/prevent that error.

Comment: How as the function is called $(...).onepage_scroll   or $(...).onepage_scroll()

Comment: @Pointy that's what bugs me too, everything works fine till I add that line ... It doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: jquery should be loaded first onepagescroll.js second

Comment: Good grief people, **read the code here**: http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js - look through there and see if you find any trace of jQuery.

Comment: Try delete call $(".main").onepage_scroll();  =)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomended to place the 3 scripts:

```
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/script.js"></script>
```

Before this one:

```
<script src="http://greenbex.com/js/onepagescroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: This would not work. Those lines need to be at the end of the `<body>`.